# Search bar with isar Database

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-isar

hi and hello everyone ,

i am new with flutter and dart

and i am start using isar database
and everything is good and ok

but i have problem with Search

i create function for search

```
  getAll(String search) async* {
    final isar = await db;
    final query = isar.books
        .where()
        .filter()
        .titleContains(search)
        .build();

    await for (final results in query.watch(fireImmediately: true)) {
      if (results.isNotEmpty) {
        yield results;
      }
    }
  }
```

and i add Search i home screen like this in TextField :

```
onChanged: (value) {
isarService.getAll(search: value);
}
```

,

but not work with me i try everthing but no work

soory for my english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your getAllBooks() just remove .build()

```
Stream<List<Book>> getAllBooks({String? search}) async* {
print(search);
final isar = await db;
final query = isar.books
    .where()
    .filter()
    .titleContains(search ?? '', caseSensitive: false);

await for (final results in query.watch(fireImmediately: true)) {
  if (results.isNotEmpty) {
    yield results;
  }
}
}
```

Convert your book_list_screen.dart class in StatefulWidget, and use a variable.

```
String search = ""; //for searching
```

Inside your TextField's onChanged()

```
onChanged: (value) {
            
    setState(() {
                search = value;
              });
             
            },
```

and inside your Expanded widget use something like this

```
Expanded(
    child: StreamBuilder<List<Book>>(
          stream: widget.isarService.getAllBooks(search: search),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
      ...
  }
            ),
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should wait for the response:

```dart
onChanged: (value) async {
await isarService.getAll(search: value);
}
```